# Use of splines in penalized regression

Tags: statistics, regression

I'm not quite sure this is the appropriate place to post the question, but hopefully someone who has a deeper understanding about the subject than me sees this.

We are given $n + 1$ data points $(x_0, y_0),(x_1, y_1), . . . ,(x_n, y_n)$ and we want to find a smooth
function $y = f(x)$ to represent the trend in these points. We define a smooth function to be
one that is continuous and has continuous first and second derivatives. One approach is to use penalized regression, i.e. minimise

$$\sum_{j=0}^{n}(y_j-f(x_j))^2+\lambda\int (f''(x))^2dx$$

where $\lambda >0$.

There is a theorem that says that the solution to this is a natural cubic spline that interpolates the data.

My question is: What is the role of $\lambda$? My lecture notes say that it is a a parameter that makes connection between the fit and the penalty. However, since the natural spline is uniquely determined by the points, won't $\lambda$ be useless in the expression?

Thanks!

Comment: What theorem says that the minimising solution to that is a natural cubic spline that interpolates the data?  I suspect the theorem may actually say that for smooth functions which make the left part of the expression $0$, a natural cubic spline minimises the right part.  But I think there may be other functions which minimise the whole expression, and these would depend on $\lambda$ - for example for very large $\lambda$ something close to a straight line

Comment: Yes, but a cubic spline minimizes the expression on the right AND makes the sum $0$ since it interpolates the data. My problem is that since we have a solution, why do we care for other ones?

Comment: There are other straighter functions (not passing through all the points) which give a lower value for the expression on the right, and a straight line using OLS regression  makes the right hand part $0$ and minimises the left hand part across straight lines.  So it is plausible that for given $\lambda$ there is a better overall  solution than either a natural cubic spline or an OLS straight line, as part of the bias/variance tradeoff

Comment: Oh, I see, the theorem says that out of all interpolating functions the spline minimizes the sum - thanks a lot!!! That really cleared up things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the theorem says that the natural cubic spline is the solution, then it means that there are other cubic splines which can be obtained by other criteria (e.g. $\lambda$). In fact, cubic splines are underdetermined by a set of points because the first and last endpoints do not place enough constraints on the system of equations. This is resolved in the case of a *natural* cubic spline by constraining the second derivatives at the first and last point to be 0.

Comment: I don't think I understand. Since the natural spline minimizes the expression then why do we care about other splines? We already have a solution

Comment: As a hypothetical, consider a spline which is meant to approximate a function about which we have _noisy_ data. How much weight do we give to the fit on the points (the sum) versus the curvature?

Comment: So you are saying that we don't really interpolate the data because of the noise? I can't follow

Comment: We do interpolate the data. We simply don't require that $f(x_i)=y_i$ at every point. If $\lambda$ is positive and our error is zero then we're at a minimum. But what if $\lambda$ is negative? Then we can get a better fit by   allowing some error $(y_i-f(x_i))^2$.

Comment: Well, $\lambda > 0$ by definition but I see what you mean. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know that $\lambda > 0$ by definition since I don't have your source available to read. It seems to me that they exhibit this general form and then prove that there is a unique solution to minimize this expression when $\lambda > 0$. Thus it is something like "if lambda is greater than zero, then..." Is the source for this question available online?